# Jquery Animation: problem with following the window scroll in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I’m trying to make a div follow the window scrollTop.

In FF it looks good but in IE (6,7) the animation jumps and causes the window scroll to jump.

I've tried easing but it didn't work.

My code:

```
        <div style="float:left;width:500px;height:4000px; background-color:Blue;">
        <br/>           
    </div>
    <div id="Div1" style="position:relative; float:left; height:4000px; width:300px;">
        <div id="sidePanel" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;width:200px; height:200px;  border:solid 1px black;">
            SIDE PANEL<br/><br/>
        <div id="info"></div>
            <br />
            <button id="showCurrTop" onclick="alert($(window).scrollTop());">$(window).scrollTop()</button>
        </div>
    </div>

        $(document).ready(function(){

             $(window).scroll(function () { 
                    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

                    $("#sidePanel").stop(false,false);
                    $("#sidePanel").animate({"top": scrollTop + 200}, 1000);

                    $("#info").html(scrollTop);

                });
          });
```

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, you want to move a div when the page is scrolled. If so, why not simply use CSS `position: fixed`?

Comment: I want it to animate like http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/sf-example-1.html (which also jumps on IE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: [Floating Div](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/floatobject)

Comment: Even though the site you linked to is going to (likely) stay around for years to come, it's good practice to paraphrase what you found for the benefit of those reading Stack Overflow. If the link ever _does_ break, the information will still be helpful.